# Automatic Numbering and Color in Table

Tags: tables, color, numbering

I'm trying to simultaneously get a column which automatically lists the row number but is colored similarly to `xcolor`'s `\rowcolors` command. That is, I'm trying to get an output similar to:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{green!60!yellow!40}{green!40!yellow!20}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2em}|p{1in}|p{1in}|}
\hline
\cellcolor{violet!20} ID & \cellcolor{violet!20} Description  & \cellcolor{violet!20} Location\\
1 & Lorem & ipsum\\
2 & Dolor & dolor\\
3 & Foo & bar\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

while using an implementation similar to:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{rownum}
\setcounter{rownum}{1}

\newcommand{\rownumber}{\arabic{rownum} \stepcounter{rownum}}

\rowcolors{2}{green!60!yellow!40}{green!40!yellow!20}

\begin{tabular}{|@{\makebox[2em][r]{\rownumber~}}|p{1in}|p{1in}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|@{\makebox[2em][r]{ID~}} | l |}{\cellcolor{violet!20}Description} & \cellcolor{violet!20} Location\\
Lorem & ipsum\\
Dolor & dolor\\
Foo & bar\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The first "target" implementation is generates:[image: Table with correct coloring, but no automatic numbering]

The implementation that uses automatic numbering generates:[image]

How can I get the coloring from the first without needing to put the numbers in manually (or prepending each line with a command)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

[image]

`>{command}` allows to include formatting commands, which be executed with each cell. Furthermore, you need to define additionally cell color with `\cellcolor{...}` inside `\multicolumn`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcounter{rownum}
\setcounter{rownum}{0}
\rowcolors{2}{green!60!yellow!40}{green!40!yellow!20}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\stepcounter{rownum}\therownum}p{1em}|p{0.75in}|p{0.75in}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{1em}|}{\cellcolor{violet!20}{ID}} & \cellcolor{violet!20}Description & \cellcolor{violet!20} Location\\
        &Lorem & ipsum\\
        &Dolor & dolor\\
        &Foo & bar\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```